# set up project for windows service application in vs2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, service, installation

I have a windows service application in vs 2012, I have created a setup project for it. The problem is that when I run setup it installs application files in directory, but the service itself is not listed in Services from task manager. so service is not set up properly

Can anybody give a clarification on how to correctly create a set up project for windows service application in vs2012.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is too general since you are not posting your code sample. 
Anyways, take a look at the [topshelf project](http://topshelf-project.com/) it basically makes it really easy to create windows services with installers and ability to debug your service as console application.

Here is a sample windows service from the docs, and you can install it by simple compiling project and then `TownCrier.exe install` from command line. You can also uninstall, setup different install credentials and retries.

```
public class TownCrier
{
    readonly Timer _timer;
    public TownCrier()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000) {AutoReset = true};
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("It is {0} an all is well", DateTime.Now);
    }
    public void Start() { _timer.Start(); }
    public void Stop() { _timer.Stop(); }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>                                 //1
        {
            x.Service<TownCrier>(s =>                        //2
            {
               s.ConstructUsing(name=> new TownCrier());     //3
               s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());              //4
               s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());               //5
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();                            //6

            x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host");        //7
            x.SetDisplayName("Stuff");                       //8
            x.SetServiceName("stuff");                       //9
        });                                                  //10
    }
}
```